# how to remove redundant value of two different genere

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If you click this link you can see the code.Problem is when i click on action it is removing redundant data but if i click on another checkbox (i.e family) then it will give the value. but if i put same value as first checkbox (i.e action) then it is showing that value.My aim is if i select two different checkbox it will show only one value

```
[
      {title:'Meet the Robinsons', genre:'action'},
      {title:'Meet the Robinsons', genre:'action'},
      {title:'MSD', genre:'family'}
   ]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Bw77D/669/

Comment: what do you want to be the ouput? i didn't understand the problem

Comment: if i click on action it will show  meet the Robinson and if i click on family it will show MSD .

Comment: if i chnage the value like[
      {title:'MSD', genre:'action'},
      {title:'Meet the Robinsons', genre:'action'},
      {title:'MSD', genre:'family'}
   ] it will show in output only meet the robinson and msd not show redundant data

Comment: if you understand please change it to this link http://jsfiddle.net/Bw77D/669/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to replace `push` by `splice` and remove `if (unique)`:

```
this.out.splice(0, 1, value);
```

Comment: otherwise i can't see

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Bw77D/722/  here two different genre but same value . My aim is if i click on two different check box it will give only one value .

Comment: if any solution please fix on this link

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, your problem is when having multiple movies, it only shows the first.

**To show all of them** you need to remove the condition `if (unique)` and leave only `this.out.push(value);`

**To show the last item of the list** you need to remove the condition `if (unique)` and replace `this.out.push(value);` by `this.out.splice(0,1,value);`

That should fix it.

http://jsfiddle.net/Bw77D/717/

Comment: now if i want to remove redundant value of genre action then what should i have to do

Comment: now if i click on action it is showing two same values . I want to see only one value and for two different genre all values are same then what should i have to do  http://jsfiddle.net/Bw77D/722/

Comment: "movies = [
          {title:'Meet the Robinsons1', genre:'action'},
          {title:'Meet the Robinsons2', genre:'action'},
          {title:'Meet the Robinsons1', genre:'family'}
       ];" if i select action and family if will show Meet the robinson and MSD

Comment: output will be Meet the  Robinson1 and  Meet the  Robinson2

Comment: by mistake i wrote msd